# CrossTab transform Null Value to "0"

Tags: sql, ms-access, report, crosstab

I need to have the CrossTab replace null counts with a zero so that my reports will have the correct totals when no data is present.

I have been told to put the Nz() function in the SQL but am having a hard time figuring out where to put it to change the `COUNT([Traffic Report Totals - Query].TrafficTypeName)` to replace Null values with 0.

I have included full SQL below:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![Report Date Range]![txtStart] DateTime, [Forms]![Report Date Range]![txtEnd] DateTime;
TRANSFORM Count([Traffic Report Totals - Query].TrafficTypeName) AS CountOfTrafficTypeName
SELECT [Traffic Report Totals - Query].CommunityGroup, [Traffic Report Totals - Query].Date
FROM [Traffic Report Totals - Query] LEFT JOIN [Contract Budget] ON [Traffic Report Totals - Query].CommunityGroup = [Contract Budget].CommunityGroup
GROUP BY [Traffic Report Totals - Query].CommunityGroup, [Traffic Report Totals - Query].Date
PIVOT [Traffic Report Totals - Query].TrafficTypeName In ("A-Initial Realtor Showing","A-Initial Visit","B-Be Back","C-Additional Contract Paperwork","C-Cancellation","C-Closing","C-Contract","C-Contract Deposit","C-Final Orientation","Completion","C-Pre-Contruction Meeting","C-Pre-Drywall Walk","C-Realtor Showing","C-WJH Showing","Email Followup","Email Inquiry","Realtor Call","Realtor Visit","Telephone Follow-Up","Telephone Inquiry","Warranty Call");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the counting fields in the Query where the data is sourced from in your example the **Traffic Report Totals - Query**. Go to the SQL of the Query then check the fields and wrap them in Nz() function.

Comment: I fixed it by doing this in the SQL of the CrossTab `TRANSFORM NZ(Count([Traffic Report Totals - Query].TrafficTypeName))+0 AS CountofTrafficTypeName`